# If $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac x{1+e^{1/x}}$ for $x\neq 0$, find the left and right hand derivatives for f = 0

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

This problem is for my Mathematical Analysis class, and I'm looking for any help I can get. The equation I am using to solve this problem is: (for left hand only)$$f'(x)=\lim_{x_o\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}$$
I believe that I am applying the formula correctly, but I believe I am misinterpreting its usefulness.

My Work:

In the above equation, $f(x_o)$ and $x_o$ both appear to go to zero as the limit of $x_o$ approaches zero from the left hand side. So I'm left with $$\lim_{x_o\to 0^-} \frac{f(x)}x=\lim_{x_o\to 0^-}\frac1{1+e^{1/x}}$$ From here do I set $x_o$ equal to $x$ and say that $f'(x)$ approaches 1 as the left hand limit approaches $0$? Graphically, this appears to make sense, but I'm not sure about the reasoning behind it. Assuming this logic is correct, I would apply the same reasoning to the right hand derivative.

Comment: Your definition of left-hand limit is slightly wrong. The left-hand derivative of $f(x)$ at the point $x_0$ is $$f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}$$ Note that the dummy variable in the limit is $x$, not $x_0$. So you are looking for $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac1{1+e^{1/x}}$$ Is that more clear?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the limit definition is a good idea. $f'(0-)=\lim_{x_o\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}$ which becomes $\lim_{x_o\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-0)}{x-0}$ with $f(x)$ your given function I get after simplification: $\lim_{x_o\to 0^-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}=1$ Can you do the case when $x$ approaches zero from the positive side? By the way, here is a graph of your function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: I'm coming back to this problem, and my answer for the right hand limit does not make sense. Essentially, it comes back to $\lim_{x\to {0^+}} \frac 1{1+e^{1/x}}$, which will again fall to 1. Graphically, it appears that the limit should approach 0, but I cannot determine why this is the case

Comment: @KevinMcDonough If x approaches zero from the positive side, then the exponent in the e-power becomes infinity. That makes the fraction become zero, not 1